# Unable to add Google Apps to Genymotion

Tags: android, sdk, genymotion

Using Google Nexus 5X, Android 6.0.0 image on genymotion and following the below steps to install -

1. Transfer Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1 to emulator, reboot the device(reboot is not working on emulator so closing the emulator and starting again)
2. Transfer open_gapps-arm-6.0-mini to emulator. This is where I am getting the below error -
   `Archive:  /sdcard/Download/open_gapps-arm-6.0-mini.zip
   inflating: app_densities.txt
   Archive:  /sdcard/Download/open_gapps-arm-6.0-mini.zip
   inflating: app_sizes.txt
   Archive:  /sdcard/Download/open_gapps-arm-6.0-mini.zip
   inflating: bkup_tail.sh
   Archive:  /sdcard/Download/open_gapps-arm-6.0-mini.zip
   inflating: gapps-remove.txt
   Archive:  /sdcard/Download/open_gapps-arm-6.0-mini.zip
   inflating: g.prop
   Archive:  /sdcard/Download/open_gapps-arm-6.0-mini.zip
   inflating: installer.sh
   Archive:  /sdcard/Download/open_gapps-arm-6.0-mini.zip
   inflating: busybox-arm
   Archive:  /sdcard/Download/open_gapps-arm-6.0-mini.zip
   inflating: xzdec-arm
   Archive:  /sdcard/Download/open_gapps-arm-6.0-mini.zip
   inflating: zip-arm
   ui_print ERROR 64: Wrong architecture to set-up Open GApps' pre-bundled   busybox
   ui_print
   update-binary terminated by exit(1)
   [ERROR][execute_update_binary] execution of update-binary ended with errors`

Some more details -
Genymotion version -2.8.0
Tried creating new emulator but that also doesn't help 
Using Genymotion Android tools

Answer (score 2):

The line "ERROR 64: Wrong architecture to set-up Open GApps' pre-bundled" in the log means that there is a clash between arm,arm64 & x86. More info at https://github.com/opengapps/opengapps/wiki/FAQ

Try installing a version of GApps with arm compatible with the device's arm.

As in your case the device is Nexus 5X, it is one of the few devices which run on arm64. So, I think arm64 version of GApps should work fine.

You can find the correct version at Gapps official site.

Answer (score 0):

Steps
1. Close your emulator of Genymotion if it is running.
2. Go to Genymotion Settings
3. ADB settings
4. Click on Use Genymotion Android tool(default)

Check screenshot :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here.
The Only way to have it working was to try every platform architecture.
-> Genymotion Custom Nexus5 Android 5.1
-> The only working Gapps was the **X86** version